# how to write urls.py in django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-urls

urls.py file which is in 1.1 version of Django :-

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('ecomstore.catalog.views',
    (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$','show_category',
        {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),
 )
```

which I understood that first argument id prefix to all views. next argument is url which has four argument one is url string(regex),second is view , third is dict passing template name and fourth is location of category.

**How to write it in Django 1.10
is following it correct way:-**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from ecommstore.catalog.views import *
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$','show_category',
        {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),
 ]
```

Comment: Are you asking a question, or sharing a solution? Is your reference to [Django 1.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/#id10) ([first released in July, 2009](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.1/)) deliberate, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You've imported the view, but you're still passing in a string as the view instead of the view function itself:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', show_category,
        {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'}, 'catalog_category'),
]
```